# Retroft post Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit 2.6. when post a request to my web server it shows error  **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.** 
I have used bellow code..

1. In android i have used to post request like bellow ..

   ```
     private void getPosts() {
       String basurl = "http://10.11.201.179:8084/TestWeb/";

       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(basurl)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build();

       JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
      Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
      parameters.put("user_id", "12345");
      parameters.put("password", "123");

     Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts(parameters);


     call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<Post>> response) {
           Log.e("response.body", response.toString());
           if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
               // textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
               return;
           }

           Log.e("response.body", response.body().toString());

           List<Post> posts = response.body();

           for (Post post : posts) {
               Log.e("name", post.getName());

               //textViewResult.append(content);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.e("***errror", t.getMessage());
       }
    });

   }
   ```
2. Here is my interface to post name JsonPlaceHolderApi

   ```
   public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
     @POST("TestS")
     Call<List<Post>> getPosts(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
    }
   ```
3. Here i have bind the response server

   ```
   public class Post {
    @SerializedName("mobile")
    @Expose
    public String mobile;

   @SerializedName("name")
   @Expose
   public String name;

   //Getter serter
   }
   ```
4. Here is my json

   ```
    {
     "name": "1",
     "mobile": "01921687433"
     }
   ```

Please help me

Comment: You are expecting a `List<Post>` but your response does not start with a `JsonArray` here . If thats your response you should be expecting  `Call<Post>` only  or modify your response as Array.

Comment: please show api response

Comment: @darwin it show error BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line

Comment: can u show the api response from postman of any other rest client, the error indicates that your are expecting a list of Post's but it returns an Json object instead of array.

Comment: may be your list of post's wrapped inside another object

Comment: @darwin post man {"out_code":"0","out_message":"Successfully Login ","user_id":"D002","name":"Enamul Haque","mobile":"01921687433","email":"","usertype":"MEM","deposit_amount":"383000"}

Comment: @darwin i have also tried like  public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, retrofit2.Response<Post> response) {
            Log.e("response.body", response.toString());
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                // textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196437/discussion-between-darwin-and-enamul-haque).